# How to get childs data javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, parent-child

Can somebody explain me what did I do wrong?

```js
let toolbarForChilds = document.getElementById("toolbar");

for (let i = 0; i < toolbarForChilds.childNodes.length; i++) {
  toolbarForChilds.childNodes[i].style.cursor = "default";
}
```

```html
<div class="sample-toolbar" id="toolbar" style="text-align: center;">
  <div id="title">#1</div>
  <div id="another thing">#2</div>
</div>
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cursor' of undefined
```

Comment: "_childNodes includes all child nodes—including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes_" - so not all nodes have a `style` property

Comment: you can use `.children` instead for just elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Node.childNodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

> `childNodes` includes all child nodes—including non-element nodes like ***text*** and ***comment*** nodes. To get a collection of only elements, use `ParentNode.children` instead.

You do not need to use `childNodes`. You can target all the elements with `querySelectorAll()` and loop through them like the following way:

```js
let toolbarForChilds = document.querySelectorAll("#toolbar div");

for (let i = 0; i < toolbarForChilds.length; i++) {
  toolbarForChilds[i].style.cursor = "default";
}
```

```html
<div class="sample-toolbar" id="toolbar" style ="text-align: center;">
    <div id ="title">#1</div>
    <div id ="another thing">#2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that childNodes not only returns [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). There are also nodes without a style attribute. As example between the html tags there are empty [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text). You should see this in your browsers console if you add `console.log(toolbarForChilds.childNodes[i]);` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is that childNodes also includes the newlines between the elements. You can `console.log` the childNodes to see them. Your code will work if you wrap it in a try-catch to skip those, although you should follow Mamun's answer for a cleaner way to do it.

```
for (let i = 0; i < toolbarForChilds.childNodes.length; i++) {
    try {
      toolbarForChilds.childNodes[i].style.cursor = "default";
    }
    catch {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`node.childNodes` returns elements without style attributes like text nodes. For only getting node elements, that is, div's: `id ="title"` & `id ="another thing"` use `node.children`. This is implemented below.

```js
let toolbarForChilds= document.getElementById("toolbar");
/* console.log(toolbarForChilds.childNodes); */
for (let i = 0; i < toolbarForChilds.children.length; i++) {
  toolbarForChilds.children[i].style.cursor = "help";
}
```

```html
<div class="sample-toolbar" id="toolbar" style ="text-align: center;">
    <div id ="title">#1</div>
    <div id ="another thing">#2</div>
</div>
```